# applying for loop between two dataframes by specific order between them

Tags: r

I have two dataframes named `df` and `df1`.

```
df<- data.frame(age = c(13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21),
                pop = c(22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30))

df1<- data.frame(age= c(11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24),
                 w = c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130,140))
```

I am trying to operate   `pop * (w_constant / w)` for four years. `w_constant` would be constant for all years and rows. in first year, `pop` start from age 17 and `w` start from age 20. for next year, `pop` and `w` change to pervious age. in every year, each column only contains 5 pop based on each age not all pop. for example, 2nd, 3rd.. value for the year 1990 would be subsequent `pop`, 27,28,29 and 30. when I move to next year `pop|age = 16`  and `w|age = 19` . and pop would be 25,26,27,28,29 for year 1991.

by the code below, I tried to do that but I have two problems: the first one is that I do not know how my loop should run for every subsequent row in each year. it seems that it just run for first row in each year. the second one is that , as shown in my code, in each next year I want the `w` and `pop` to start from previous age , but I do not how to specify that. for one I can simple use `-1` but for next year it could be difficult for me. here is my codes:

```
result_df <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 5, ncol = 4))
colnames(result_df) <- c(1990, 1991, 1992, 1993)

w_constant <- df1$w[df1$age == 15]
w <- df1$w[df1$age == 20 ]
pop <- df$pop[df$age == 17]

for (i in 1:4) {
  
  result_df[,i] <- pop * (w_constant / w)
 
  w <- df1$w[df1$age == 20 - 1]
  pop <- df$pop[df$age == 17 - 1]
 
}
```

my expected output would be like this :

```
   X1990 X1991 X1992 X1993
1  13.0 13.88 15.00 16.42
2  13.5 14.44 15.62 17.14
3  14.0 15.00 16.25 17.85
4  14.5 15.55 16.87 18.57
5  15.0 16.11 17.50 19.28
```

Comment: It's difficult to tell how your `df` and `df1` relate to years or your `result_df`. Its also unclear what `w_c` is. Could you clarify a bit about what you are trying to do? If you could manually show the calculations in a few cells of `result_df` that would be very helpful. Good luck!

Comment: @jpsmith beat me by a few mins ... so I save the words. Can you at least elaborate how your `w_constant` , `w`, and ` pop` are related to the years you are referring? With the code you have, you appear to subset vectors of your datta frame, e.g. `df1$w[df1$age == 20 ]` what do you achieve with this?

Comment: You also shouldn't use `df1$w[df1$age == 20 - 1]` or `df1$w[df1$age == 20 - 1]` because that will return a boolean `TRUE`/`FALSE` vector the length of the number of rows in the data frame (try it). You should do something like `df1$w[df1$age == (20 - i)]` - note the parentheses around the numbers and the use of `i`

Comment: @mehmo we got that `w_constant` is a constant. Thus, we set it once and forget about it. With `first year` you seem to refer to X1990 - but this is basically the way you order your results. To calculate the 5 values for 1990 (first year) you start with `pop|age =17` and `w|age=20`. That is what you hardcoded before the loop. How do you calculate the 2nd, 3rd, ...5th value for the year 1990? The `5 pop` are these the consecutive values for pop? Then you move to the next year (result column ~ X1991) and set the start values to the "previous"  age. Does this mean `pop|age = 14` and `w|age = 19`?

Comment: @mehmo please edit your question to include these details, don’t add them in the comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it took a while to decipher what you are doing.

In principle, you have a `function` (read calculate) that operates on a subset of one of your data frame variables, i.e. `pop` from `df`. The other values are determined on the basis of a given age condition (i.e. `w` is a simple lookup, `w_constant` is also a fixed value looked up once).

A way to code this is to generalise it in - actually - a function.
You can then think about whether this can be done as a loop (and over what to loop). ((Note: your loop above is actually a loop to generate your `result_df`, you are not looping over your data frames as such))

** your algorithm **

Be sure to understand how subsetting in R works. You want to extract `5 consecutive values` from `df`:

```
# this only returns values (for which the condition holds)
# the way your df is constructed (individual ages) it only returns 1 value

df$pop[df$age == 17]
[1] 26

# what you want is 5 consecutive values starting from age == 17:
df$pop[df$age %in% c(17:(17 + 5))]
[1] 26 27 28 29 30

# the rest is then simple applying your algorithm to the subsetted vector
pop1 <- df$pop[df$age %in% c(17:(17 + 5))]

pop1 * (w_constant / w)
[1] 13.0 13.5 14.0 14.5 15.0
```

**do it once (generalise what you do)**

So, let's check how we can generalise this.

Inputs:

- both data frames to look up what we need
- one age to look up your w value
- one pop start age
- a constant   (we put this inside the function, but you could input this as well, if needed)

```
mehmo_function <- function(pop_start_age, w_lookup_age, df, df1){
    # first we determine the constant, you could supply this as an argument if this changes
    w_constant <- df1$w[df1$age == 15] 
    
    # now lookup w
    w <- df1$w[df1$age == w_lookup_age ]
    
    # now loop up consecutive pops
    pops <- df$pop[df$age %in% c(pop_start_age:(pop_start_age + 4))]
    
    # calc result vector
    res_vec <- pops * (w_constant / w)
    return(res_vec)
}
```

This yields for

```
# your first year
mehmo_function(17, 20, df, df1) 
[1] 13.0 13.5 14.0 14.5 15.0

# your next year
mehmo_function(16, 19, df, df1) 
[1] 13.88889 14.44444 15.00000 15.55556 16.11111
```

I leave the rest to you.

If you want to express this in a loop, do so.
you may just want to run the function 4 times for the specific years and load it into your result data frame.

Comment: thanks @Ray but why next year contains 6 rows?

Comment: ahhh ... you got me ... the `pop_start_age + 5` must be `pop_start_age + 4`. In the first year there are only 5 values, for the second year and next years it would generate 6 then. Code above updated. Well spotted, @mehmo